Ellie from Blender Deforms when Keyframing
Downloaded Ellie from Blender to practice walk cycle, everything has been working except when I try to make a key frame of a pose, the boots become deformed, and its specifically has been always the boots, everything else stays in position. I tested this model in another computer, and it worked. Its specifically my computer that has something messed up. Please help, I am going insane. Its also specifically whenever I press A, in order to select all the bones. Whenever I do one individual bone, it works fine, but I need it to have it all selected so the animation will work properly.



